# facebook scraper doesn't see og tags

Tags: facebook, web-scraping

when facebook share debugger is scraping the page it shows this warning:

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

although all these meta tags are in the page when we look at the page source code like below:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
<meta property="og:title" content="asaaaa" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="900" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="578" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="+INP" />
<meta property="og:description" content="saaasaaa" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="sasdaaaa">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.inp.plus/news/45792" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

the thing is it does not read those tags with this type of link
/news/34131

but it does read the same tags with other type of links
articles/321

with tags like below:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
<meta property="og:title" content="asdaaaa" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.inp.plus/userfiles/Image/articles/2018/05/20180511_39395.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="900" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="581" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="+INP" />
<meta property="og:description" content="fdaaaa" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="asdfaaa">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.inp.plus/articles/299" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

I mean is there a difference between them to make the second one seen by the facebook scraper not the first one.

Comment: I just went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and rescraped the first URL and it worked

Comment: this is the problem, some times it works rarely and most of the time is not like if you do scrape again it will be gone.